# Network Manager drops wifi and won't remember password

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, network-manager

I just updated my (K)Ubuntu 12.04 certified Asus laptop to Kubuntu 13.10. Now wifi drops at least every 10 minutes, and sometimes several times per minute. It's a wireless-n network with WPA2-PSK. It never dropped before the update.

What's more, network manager somehow doesn't remember the wifi password, so I'm forced to type it in every time the connection drops (KDE Daemon pop-up). When I edit the connection however, the password is right there on the wireless security tab, so evidently it's being kept somewhere. The connection is set to auto connect and usable by all users. I have tried deleting and re-adding it several times, to no avail.

Here's my wifi hardware:

```
 *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 00
   serial: e0:06:e6:09:0d:15
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.11.0-12-generic firmware=0.34 ip=192.168.1.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:52 memory:de800000-de80ffff
```

THANKS for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please do:

```
echo "options rt2800pci nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800pci.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv rt2800pci
sudo modprobe -v rt2800pci
```

watch for errors.